# Material Table sytling using react component

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I need to wrap the search Field around a button, for that I would want to call a React Component. Is there any way I can do that. I have predefined a Button Component, basically I want to integrate the Search with that Button Component.

This is the codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-haze-8xnq4j?file=/src/App.js

Need to find a way to integrate button with Search feature.